# How to deduce types by template integers in C++

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I have code:

```
template<int I, typename = void>
struct indexed_type {
  using type = void;
  indexed_type() { std::cout << "I is void: " << I << std::endl; }
};


template<int I>
struct indexed_type<I, typename std::enable_if<I == 1, char>::type> {
  using type = char;
  indexed_type() { std::cout << "I is char: " << I << std::endl; }
};
```

But after an initialization:

```
indexed_type<0>{};
indexed_type<1>{}; // not happens always
```

I have got not worked second variant always :(

Could you help me to get working the second variant of specialization ?

--
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your specialization will only be used if the second type is given and is `char`, like `indexed_type<1, char>`. Without specifying the second parameter, it defaults to `void` (`indexed_type<1>` is the same as `indexed_type<1, void>`, which does not select the second specialization).

You probably want to specialize based on the value of `I`:

```cpp
template<int I>
struct indexed_type;

template<>
struct indexed_type<0> {
  using type = void;
  static constexpr int I = 0;
  indexed_type() { std::cout << "I is void: " << I << std::endl; }
};

template<>
struct indexed_type<1> {
  using type = char;
  static constexpr int I = 1;
  indexed_type() { std::cout << "I is char: " << I << std::endl; }
};
```